# How to setup sudoers for Apache web service?

Tags: php, apache2, sudo

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
apache ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
me ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

In Fedora both works:

```
http://localhost/test
echo shell_exec("sudo dmidecode | grep UUID"); // nothing shows to encrypt/decrypt licenses

php -r "..license..";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu, apache runs as the `www-data` user. If you want to use sudo without a password from a web page, you should probably limit the commands that it can run.

Comment: +1 You will really want to limit the commands scope.

Comment: So, how do we limit the commands that it can run?