# Call a shell script from PHP, run as root

Tags: command-line, sudo, php

I'm running ubuntu 11.10. I want to be able to call a shell script from php and run that script as root. When my php attempts to call the shell script as root --like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo /var/www/my_script.sh')
```

I get this error in the apache log:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I've changed the owner of the php script to root:root. I've added this line to  sudoers:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD:/var/www/my_script.php
```

I realize that I'm supposed to comment out this line in sudoers:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

However, there's no such line in my sudoers file. What do I need to do to get past this error?

Comment: You cannot use SUDO or SU in PHP.

Comment: Why can't you ?

Comment: You can: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64465/how-to-setup-sudoers-for-apache-web-service

Answer (score 3):

Your sudoers line is granting access to execute "my_script.php" while your shell_exec is invoking "my_script.sh".
When a password is not required, the requiretty option should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Use "suexec"... in Ubuntu 10.04 server:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-suexec-common
```

Enable suexec:

```
sudo a2enmod suexec
```

Edit the config file to match your site:

```
sudo -e /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data
```

Then see [Using suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html#usage) on Apache.org to configure the Apache config file(s).

Another approach...

Allow the www-data user to run to run *program1* and *program2* with no password:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add to the contents of the sudoers file:

```
User_Alias WWW_USER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias WWW_COMMANDS = /sbin/program1, /sbin/program2
WWW_USER ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: WWW_COMMANDS
```

Save.

Yet another is with [suPHP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45496/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-files-to-a-website-on-a-lamp-server/46471#46471)

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as user: apache/www-data or root if needed). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//Setting the second argument in getShell():
//true will return a shell with root
//false will return a shell with the php execution user
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/var/www/my_script.sh');
```